# CustomPouchError

Tags: react-native, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to sync my local DB to remote one like this:

```js
const DB_NAME = "my_db";
const REMOTE_DB_URL ="http://<admin>:<password>/<ip-address>:5984/my_db";

const localDB = new PouchDB(DB_NAME);
const remoteDB = new PouchDB(REMOTE_DB_URL);

localDB.sync(remoteDB)
.then(() => {
    console.log("Sync done");
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This is the error I get:

> message:"getCheckpoint rejected with " name:"unknown" result:{ok:
> false, start_time: Mon Dec 18 2017 14:14:03 GMT+0100 (CET), docs_read:
> 0, docs_written: 0, doc_write_failures: 0, ...} status: 0

Local DB is working fine, but when try to replicate/sync to remote, always get error above

I am using

- React Native 0.50.0
- pouchdb-react-native: 6.3.4
- Remote DB is CouchDB 2.1.1

Comment: Remote is CouchDB 2.1.1

Comment: Did CouchDB has been built from source? Do you have a proxy or firewall that could cause any issues?

Comment: @AlexisCôté yes i have Firewall. It's Azure Ubuntu VM, but i added :5984 port to Firewall. And also I added *bind_address=0.0.0.0* to configuration.

Comment: Have you built Couchdb from sources?

Comment: Nope, with apt-get, why?

Comment: Someone had issues with checkpoint since CouchDB was compiled with a wrong erlang version.

Comment: How can you be sure that's the problem? What's the fastest way to fix this?

Comment: @AlexisCôté, it wasn't a problem, issu is fixed

Answer (score 3):

To sync your CouchDB databases follow these steps:

**Step 1:**
Serve the remote DB through https, not http by using CouchDB's native SSL support, as indicated here:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.3.0/ssl.html

**Step 2:**
Make sure you have CORS enabled, as indicated here: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.3.0/cors.html